# Recover unallocated disk space

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility, partition

I would like to recover some unallocated (?) disk space on an external hard drive /dev/disk2 is 1TB but I only see a 250GB partition. Here is a terminal screenshot and a Disk Utility one.

[image: terminal]
[image: disk utility]

Is there any way I could add the remaining 750 GB to the existing partition disk2s2 or create a new disk2s3?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I’m curious if the + is clickable in the bottom image - can the graphical utility add an HFS partition?

Comment: @bmike it is, but I think it's just using the free space from the partition. Image here: https://postimg.cc/qtKH9zcL

Comment: Popa: Post the output from the command `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size`. This will show where the container resides on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up formatting the whole thing after doing a back-up